# Confusion about EstimatedProcess::ntsprt error

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, warning-messages, estimation

Given the data as follows,

```
Oridata = {5,19,24,22,23,20,14,11,13,15,11,8,7,5,5,4,4,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}

CumData = {5, 24, 48, 70, 93, 113, 127, 138, 151, 166, 177, 185, 192, 197, 202,
206, 210, 213, 215, 217, 218, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219, 219}  
(*cumulative data for process fitting*)
```

I am receiving the follwing error when i am considering `CumData` for CompoundPoissonProcess[$\lambda$, LogSeriesDistribution[$\theta$]]]

`EstimatedProcess::ntsprt: One or more data points are not in the support of the process CompoundPoissonProcess[`$\lambda$`,LogSeriesDistribution[`$\theta$`]]`

But with the same `CumData` if applied as

`EstimatedProcess[CumData,CompoundPoissonProcess[`$\lambda$`,PoissonDistribution[` $\phi$`]]]`. It estimated as

```
CompoundPoissonProcess[1.,PoissonDistribution[8.56]]
```

If further check with a different model,

`EstimatedProcess[CumData,CompoundPoissonProcess[`$\lambda$`,NegativeBinomialDistribution[` $n,p$`]]]`.

It estimated as

```
CompoundPoissonProcess[1.,NegativeBinomialDistribution[0.859715,0.0912676]]
```

I'm wondering why in later cases there are no errors.

Kindly assist, what causes an such error and how to use `CumData` for parameter estimation for  CompoundPoissonProcess[$\lambda$,LogSeriesDistribution[$\theta$]].

Comment: It seems to happen because of the duplicate 219 elements in your cumulative data. Zero isn't in the support of `LogSeriesDistribution`. You cannot fit a `CompoundPoissonProcess` with a non-zero jump size distribution because the last six elements of your data have no jumps.

Comment: @flinty thanks. This is valuable information for me. Now i tried, with  `CumData[[1 ;; -5]]`, it estimated as `CompoundPoissonProcess[1., LogSeriesDistribution[0.973749]]`. 
Would it be the right approach to reduce data points? If no, then any other alternative will be appreciated.

Comment: If you generate some paths from the process e.g with `RandomFunction[
  CompoundPoissonProcess[1., LogSeriesDistribution[0.973749]], {50}]["Values"]` do they look reasonable to you? I don't know what physical thing your data represents so I couldn't comment on whether its right to exclude those points - but if you expect zero jumps in your data you may want a more appropriate distribution that allows it.

Comment: Indeed, I didnt get effective mean near to 219 if `Mean@(RandomFunction[   CompoundPoissonProcess[1., LogSeriesDistribution[0.973749]], {50},1000]["LastValues"])`. Possibly the estimation way might not appropirate. 
But I required this model only for some reason.